# Well defined norm in quotient space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

**I need to show that the norm in quotient space is well defined.**

Let $X$ a Banach space and consider $M \subseteq X$ a closed  subspace. Consider in $x$ the equivalence relation $x \equiv y \iff x-y \in M$, and let $X/M$ the quotient set. The equivalence class of $x$ is the set $[x]=x+M = \{ x+z | z \in M \}$.

In $X/M$ consider the function $\|\, \|:X/M\to [0, \infty[$ by  that the expression $\|[x]\|=\|x+M\| = \inf \{ \|x-z\| \mid z \in M\}$ defines a norm in $X/M$.

a) I showed that $\|[x]\| = \inf \{ \|x-z\| \mid z \in M\}$ defines a norm in $X/M$.

b) I need show that the norm is well defined. I'm not sure what to show.

Is this?  "      If $[x], [y]\in X/M$ and $[x]=[y]$ then  $\| [x]\|=\| [y]\|$"?

If what I have to prove is correct, I showed this:

Let $x,y\in X$ so that $[x]=[y]$. If $[x]=[y]$ then $x+M=y+M$ or $y-x+M=0+M$. Now,

$$
\begin{align*}
 \| [x]\| &=\| x+M\| \\
&=\| x+0+M\|\\
&=\| (x+M)+(0+M)\|\\
&=\| (x+M)+(y-x+M)\| \\
&=\| x+y-x+M\|\\
&= \| y+M\|\\
&= \|[y]\|
\end{align*}
$$

Is correct? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's all correct, but you seem to have implicitly used that $\|[x]\|$ equals to $\inf\{\|z\|:z\in x+M\}$. 
Then the claim Indeed follows as $[x]=[y]$ means $x+M=y+M$.